Is Rev 3,10, 11 saying that the church of Philadelphia was raptured?
What does the message to Philadelphia in Rev 3 mean? In verses 10 & 11 specifically it seems to be promised that the Philadelphian church would be raptured during/before THE tribulation or some time of tribulation. But the church of Philadelphia is no more & Jesus hasn't returned yet and tribulation hasn't started yet and Philadelphia was never raptured.

Rev 3:10, 11 - Because you have kept My command to persevere, I will
also keep you from the hour of testing that is about to come upon the
whole world, to test those who dwell on the earth. I am coming soon.
Hold fast to what you have, so that no one will take your crown.


Where is rapture even mentioned?

Before hoping to understand if verses 10 and 11 mean that a gathering of Christians in a location called Philadelphia were 'raptured' into heaven before some period of tribulation, the time element for the whole of chapter 3 must be made clear.
All of Christ's declarations to seven assemblies of Christians in Asia Minor, just before the end of the 1st century, form part of an initial over-view of global events that will culminate in global opposition that will increase in proportion to the nearness of Christ's spectacular return. At the last, the deluded world along with all false religion will gather in unity to try to finally destroy the beleagured and diminishing remnant of the saints. This may be called 'the Great Tribulation', to distinguish it from on-going tribulation that has afflicted Christ's Church from the 1st century till today.
Now, this opening section of the book of Revelation ends at the end of chapter three. This is obvious by ch. 4 vs. 1 saying, "After this I looked, and, behold, a door was opened in heaven." There is a sudden switch from what had been happening to Christians on earth, to John getting to see a vision of unseen, heavenly matters that required the Lamb opening seven seals. The opening of the sixth seal ushers in the Last Judgment, which ends history. The Last Judgment is the Last Day.
The second section is chapters 4 to 6 inclusive. Then 7:1 shows a new section is starting, with "And after these things..." John sees something else. There are clear indications throughout of a total of 7 sections to the book of Revelation. Each section starts with aspects of what cannot be known to Christians except for God revealing those unseen, spiritual matters, and each section ends with the Last Judgment. Each section adds new information to what had gone before. Each section goes back and elevates understanding of all that has to happen from Christ's ascension to heaven, till his descending from there at the Last Day.
The Revelation repeats its narrative seven times. Each section shows the same cycle, covering the same period as that which had preceded, namely, the era from the ascension to the Day of Judgment. Only then can we see that chapters 3 and 4 first details Christ's dealings with his Church (as represented by Ephesus, Smyrna, Pergamos, Thyatira, Sardis and Philadelphia.) Before the Revelation deals with judgment on the world, Christ judges his people:

"For judgment must begin at the house of God, and if it first begin at
us, what shall the end be of them that obey not the gospel of God? And
if the righteous scarcely be saved, where shall the ungodly and the
sinner appear?" 1 Peter 4:17-19 A.V.

This view then means that chapters 3 and 4 are not speaking of literal groups of believers in Asia Minor (or anywhere else on Earth for that matter), either at the end of the 1st century or at any other time anyone cares to mention. Throughout the period from Christ's return to heaven until he unexpectedly starts the Day of Resurrection and Judgment, the warnings and encouragements given in chapters 3 and 4 are lessons for every Christian. Christians who have died so far have suffered persecution, hatred and tribulation to lesser or greater degrees. This will continue to be the norm, but getting worse, until the final events that culminate in the greatest tribulation there has ever been, as Satan succeeds in foisting his massive deception on the whole Earth - apart from the elect, who (knowing what the Revelation shows they must look out for) will not be deceived. But Christ does not appear until that climax has been reached.
This means that every generation of Christians must live in expectation of being the one that witnesses Christ's coming in glory and great power. That is how the 1st century Christians lived. Sadly, as centuries pass, there seems to be less and less conviction that Christ keeps judging his Church until the final Judgment Day.

"Where is the promise of his coming? For since the fathers fell
asleep, all things continue as from the beginning of creation... But
the heavens and the earth which are now, by the same word are kept in
store, reserved unto fire against the day of judgment and perdition of
ungodly men." 2 Peter 3:3-7 A.V.

This answer says "No, there was no 'church of Philadelphia that was raptured'." To get the grasp of the argument presented, please read The Revelation of Jesus Christ by John Metcalfe - http://www.johnmetcalfepublishintrust.co.uk/contact_us.htm

Answer
According to Revelation 3:10, 11, the Church in Philadelphia will be “kept (G5083 teireo)” from the Trial just as they “kept (G5083 teireo)” the Word of patience.
There is no mention of any rapture.
Explanation
(a) What is the Word of patience?

“And those in the good ground, these are the ones who in a right and
good heart, hearing the Word, they hold it and bear fruit in
patience” (Luke 8:15).


“The seed is the Word of God” (verse 11).

So, the Word of patience is the Scripture.
The Church in Philadelphia “kept” the Scripture and the commandments against all odds.
Jesus promises that He will “keep” them from the hour of Trial against all odds.
The Church in Philadelphia did not “rapture” the Word of patience. So Jesus also will not “rapture” them during the hour of Trial.
(b) What is the hour of Trial?
All the trials are localized, that is, these are limited to certain geographical area.
But the Trial Jesus mentions here is going to be universal:

“the hour of trial which is going to come on all the habitable
world in order to try those dwelling on the earth”.

Which one is He referring to?

“For then there will be great tribulation, such as has not
been from the beginning of the world until now, no, and never will
be. And if those days had not been cut short, no human being
(believer or unbeliever) would be saved. But for the sake of the elect
(believers) those days will be cut short.” (Mat 24:21-22).

The Great Affliction/Tribulation also is universal as otherwise no Gentile human life would be spared.
Thus we understand that “the hour of Trial” = the Great Tribulation.
There is only one conclusion that is possible here: that the Church in Philadelphia is the period of Church history just prior to the Great Tribulation that comes just before the end of the Age.
Conclusion
The first century Church in Philadelphia was a “shadow” of “things to come” (courtesy Col 2:17).
Jesus reveals to John about “the things you (John) see, both the things that are now (the Philadelphian church in Turkey) and the things that will happen afterward” (the Philadelphian era at the end of the Age (Rev 1:19; GNB).
Jesus will not take them away from the Great Tribulation (GT) but will protect them through the GT just as they kept the Word of patience not away from but “through” persecution.

@ Nephesh Roi - I added some bold type to make answer more clear. Okay? None of the wording is changed.

@RayGrant - Thank you very much. I appreciate it.


Because thou hast kept the word of my patience, I also will keep thee from the hour of temptation, which shall come upon all the world, to try them that dwell upon the earth. Rev 3:10

The context is in the verses previous.
The speaker is Christ Jesus who has the key of David (Isa 22:22).  What He opens, no man shuts and what He shuts, no man opens (Rev 3:7).
They of the Philadelphian church kept His word and did not deny His name (Rev 3:8).
They are contrasted with the false synagogue who do not have Christ (Rev 3:9).
Because the Philadelphians remained true to Christ, He will guard, care for, keep in the same state them from the season of trial that comes upon the world to try those who dwell on earth.
With those things in mind, some believe Revelation was written post 70AD, while others believe it was written before 70AD.
How will God "keep" them from the trial, yet make the distinction between their faith and the false?  By rapturing them?  Or by sending them a letter warning them, as Christ did in Matthew 24 or Luke 21, about the destruction of the Temple?
So, to answer the OP, there was no rapture, but there was tribulation.

The answer to this question depends greatly on one's presupposition about the book of Revelation should be understood.  For example, in understanding Rev 2, 3 we will arrive at very different conclusions such as:
1. The Seven Churches are Literal 1st century churches
Under this assumption, this could either mean that either

God spared the Philadelphian church the persecution that came to other churches
God miraculously raptured the church and invading forces found no Christians - THIS DID NOT OCCUR, so is not a possibility

2. The Seven Churches represent historical periods in Christian church history
Under this assumption, it simply means that the Philadelphian church occurred at a time in Christian history that allowed it to avoid significant church persecution
3. The seven Churches represent idealized classes of Christians throughout church history
Under this assumption, such spiritually weak Christians as described in the Philadelphian church are spared significant spiritual trials; compare 1 Cor 10:13.
There are more possibilities but all these show that Rev 3:10, 11 does not necessarily require that the members of the Philadelphian church are raptured before being persecuted, although that is not excluded.

Re.#2: some relate these to a 3½ year physical preservation of saints, until Christ's return:
Luke 21:36: "Watch therefore, and pray always that you may be counted worthy to escape all these things that will come to pass, …".
Revelation 3:10: "Because you have kept My command to persevere, I also will keep you from the hour of trial which shall come upon the whole world, …".
Revelation 12:6: "Then the woman [the true Church] fled into the wilderness, where she has a place prepared by God, that they should feed her there one thousand two hundred and sixty days.".

@RayButterworth - I made no attempt in my list above to be exhaustive. There are many more variations on these prophetic methods

Hey Dottard
Thank you for your answer.                Do you think

that its possible to interpret the passage this way: the church of Philadelphia stands for the faithful followers of Christ, specifically newly believing and/or spiritually weak followers in the end times. I think verse 13 supports this - "says to the churchES" - that its a metaphor for ALL believers, especially future ones. The passage could hold a double meaning: that the Philadelphians were protected from f.e. persecution by Nero but also philadelphian-like Christians will be protected during THE tribulation. Also can we even proove that the real philadelphian church doesnt exist anymore?

I dont know if the biblical City of Philadelphia still exists under a different Name today, but IF it does, there could be descendants of the original philadelphian church members attending the church. Maybe it IS literal in God protecting the members blessed descendants of the still existing philadelphian church in the future?

Alaşehir is a municipality and district of Manisa Province, Turkey, and has about 45 mosques. It was founded in antiquity as Philadelphia ( Φιλαδέλφεια, i.e., "the city of him who loves his brother"), and was known as such until it was conquered by the Ottomans in 1390.  As Philadelphia, Alaşehir was a highly important center in the Early Christian and Byzantine periods. It remained a strong center of Orthodox Christianity until the early 20th century, and remains a titular see of the Roman Catholic Church. Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ala%C5%9Fehir

Good point on the total destruction of the church at Philadelphia . . . along with ALL the other churches in Anatolia (there were more than seven). Prophecy is subtle and sometimes has both near and long term fulfillments. Jesus promised the church at Philadelphia that he would guard or spare them from a tribulation that would come upon the entire world! What tribulation was that and how were they guarded or spared?

@andimjustso - your suggestion would come under my #3 above.

@RayButterworth "The woman" is actually Israel, not the church, the body of Christ.  The one true church today is filling Christ's body, and is God's "husbandry" (1 Cor 3:9), not bride, which is new Jerusalem (Rev 21:2).
